# Dictionary<(string, string, string), List<object>> how to get value that match 1 key of this kind of dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that uses a combination of string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<People> listName = new List<People>(){
        new People(){firstname = "David", middlename = "Broom", lastname = "Lightning", value = 1},
        new People(){firstname = "Dave", middlename = "Cak", lastname = "Londo", value = 2},
        new People(){firstname = "Chris", middlename = "Vanglein", lastname = "Walls", value = 3},
        new People(){firstname = "Rudy", middlename = "Affair", lastname = "Master", value = 4}};

        Dictionary<(string, string, string), List<People>> data = listName
            .Where(x => x.value != 0)
            .GroupBy(x => (x.firstname, x.middlename, x.lastname))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
    }

    public class People {
        public string firstname {get; set;}
        public string middlename {get; set;}
        public string lastname {get; set;}
        public int value {get; set;}
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/dGTHv7

how to get a value when I just have 2 key firstname and lastname.

I want to get all that match firstname and lastname and ignore middlename.

Comment: This declaration isn't valid in C#, `listName.Where(x => x.value <> 0)` the entire snippet isn't compile. There is also no `value` member in `People` class. Please, provide minimal reproducible sample

Comment: ok got it, thanks!

Comment: So do you want to get Distinct values by firstname and lastname?

Comment: yeah i want to get value from a dictionary when i just have 2 key firstname and lastname

Comment: is there a way or not ?

Comment: Dictionary is just that, Dictionary, you get a match for a key, or not. If you want match based on two values, make the key with only those values. Dictionary does not allow fuzzy matching.

Comment: It isn't fully clear, what are you asking about. Can you just group using two keys, instead of 3 ones, `x => (x.firstname, x.middlename)`?

Comment: i can't group using just 2 keys, because sometimes i need to get data with other combination like firstname and middlename or just middlename

Comment: @D.845574 - "sometimes i need to get data with other combination" - then why not have (or create on demand) dedicated dictionaries for those situations?

Comment: because i get a filter inside looping, i don't think it's good to select data every loop to create dictionary isn't it gonna give me a huge costs on performance ?

Comment: @D.845574 - yes, it will cost if you do it every loop. There are several ways around it. Loop first to gather, what dictionaries you'll need, create them, loop again using them. Or just start looping and every time you encounter a "new" set of criterias, create a dedicated dictionary on demand _once_ and reuse it. Or the first suggestion with a twist: define a threshold; if there are less than X times filtering by criteria combination A, then go with List+Where instead. That might be the most performant, but you should thoroughly profile the performance and see what's best for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point of having a dictionary where the key is a combination of these 3 information if you need to retrieve data with only 2 information.

What about parsing the list directly?

```
var matchingPeople = listName.Where(p => p.firstname == "myfirstname" && p.lastname == "mylastname");
```

EDITED:
Then you need to do that:

```
var listName = new List<People>
{
    new People { firstname = "David", middlename = "Broom", lastname = "Lightning", value = 1 },
    new People { firstname = "Dave", middlename = "Cak", lastname = "Londo", value = 2 },
    new People { firstname = "Chris", middlename = "Vanglein", lastname = "Walls", value = 3 },
    new People { firstname = "Rudy", middlename = "Affair", lastname = "Master", value = 4 }
};

var data = listName
    .Where(x => x.value != 0)
    .GroupBy(x => (x.firstname, x.middlename, x.lastname))
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());

var myfirstname = "David";
var mylastname = "Broom";
var matchingPeople = data.Where(x => x.Key.firstname == myfirstname && x.Key.lastname == mylastname).SelectMany(x => x.Value);
```

You need to use `.Where(...)` to filter the data, and `.Select(...)` to select the `.Value` part of the dictionary. Because `.Value` is a list, the result would be a `List` of `List` so use `.SelectMany` instead of `.Select` to aggregate these `List` into a single `list`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, my real problem is suppose to use dictionary and i happen to  just have 2 key like firstname and lastname but i want to get all data that match it.

Comment: Note that with this solution, you'll lose the benefit of the fast access of a dictionary. It'll be just as slow, maybe even slower than the simple List+Where approach. -- Maybe you're looking for [Lookup](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2). But be aware, that building a lookup (or a dictionary) has costs, and you'll only benefit, if you're looking up several similar key structures at a time. For example look up 100 entries by firstname/lastname => create a dedicated lookup. Then 500 by middlename => another lookup. Then 3 by middle/last => probably not worth it.